# Ubuntu 12.04 - Ctrl+T does not work in browsers

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04.

At the beginning I used Unity, I downloaded and installed Chrome, Ubuntu tweak (where I configured my favorite shortcuts) and decided to switch to Gnome-classic (Unity was so slow on my machine). Unfortunately in both Firefox and Chrome shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work (But others shortcuts work well). Maybe I misassigned it by mistake or there is another magic.

How can I check list of all shortcuts on my system.?

I tried in keyboard settings, gnome advanced settings, dconf editor - no trafe after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
Is there a way to assigne/force it again?